# EJB injection in Glassfish webapp

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, cdi, ejb-3.1, glassfish-3

I've got an app that is trying to use @EJB annotation to inject remote references to EJBs in my ejb.jar file.  I'm getting inconsistent results.  In one case, I have a listener in web.xml that gets called and apparently has the EJB injected correctly, since I can see it connecting to the EJB and calling methods on it.  In another class (a struts2 action) I get NPE when it tries to access the EJB reference.  As far as I can tell, they're identical calls, in Java classes that live in the same .war file.

As a work around, I added code in the constructor to lookup the EJBs by their global JNDI names, and it works fine.  I just can't figure out why one @EJB works and not another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you inject EJBs in Struts 2 actions? Are you using CDI? Are you using the [Struts2 CDI plugin](http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/html/dev@struts.apache.org/2009-12/msg00024.html)?

**Update:** The problem is that the container is not creating the Struts objects, Struts is, so the container doesn't get the opportunity to inject anything. You'll have to use the mentioned [plugin for CDI](http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/html/dev@struts.apache.org/2009-12/msg00024.html) to enable injection in your actions.

If you want to give it a try, get Struts 2 sources:

```
svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/struts/struts2/trunk/ struts2
```

Then `cd` into the `struts2` directory and run the following command (this will compile the required modules for the `struts-cdi-plugin`)

```
mvn install -pl plugins -am
```

Then get the sources of the cdi-plugin:

```
svn co https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/struts/sandbox/trunk/struts2-cdi-plugin/
```

And compile it:

```
mvn install
```

Now, with the following dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-cdi-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javassist</groupId>
  <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

I was able to get an EJB injected in an Action:

```
public class HelloWorld extends ActionSupport {

    @Inject
    HelloEJB helloEjb;

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        setMessage(helloEjb.getMessage());
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    private String message;

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

}
```

See https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/struts/sandbox/trunk/struts2-cdi-example/ for an example.

Comment: No, just a straight @EJB annotation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  This neatly explains why my listener (instantiated by the container from a web.xml entry) worked but my actions (instantiated by struts) did not.  I just assumed that any annotated class would get processed via some sort of classloader voodoo.  Is this sort of thing documented anywhere?

Comment: @g051051 The listener is a so called "managed" component and injection works (since Java EE 5, see http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2EE/intro_ee5/#injection for example). Java EE 6 goes beyond this limitation by making injection possible in any POJO using CDI (but you have to use CDI or CDI "aware" frameworks).